# How I can set a ImageIndex in my TreeView by a if statement?

Tags: c#, xml, image, treeview, nodes

hi how i can set a image for my treeView nodes... I have a parent and a child node.

here is my code:

```
private void btnShowLicstate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            treeLic.Nodes.Clear(); 

            string command = "\"C:\\lmxendutil.exe\" -licstatxml -host lwserv005 -port 6200";

            string output = ExecuteCommand(command);
            string final_output = output.Substring(90, output.Length - 90);

            XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(final_output));



            var xDoc = XDocument.Load(xr); 
                TreeNode root = new TreeNode();
                LoadTree(xDoc.Root.Element("LICENSE_PATH"), root);
                treeLic.Nodes.Add(root);

                treeLic.ImageList = imageList1; 

        }

 public void LoadTree(XElement root, TreeNode rootNode)
        {
            foreach (var e in root.Elements().Where(e => e.Attribute("NAME") != null))
            {
                var node = new TreeNode(e.Attribute("NAME").Value);
                rootNode.Nodes.Add(node);

                if (e.Name == "FEATURE")
                {
                    node.SelectedImageIndex = 1; 

                }
                else if (e.Name == "USER")
                {
                    node.SelectedImageIndex = 0;

                }

                LoadTree(e, node);
            }
        }
```

my problem is that i have everyone the same picture but i want for FEATURE the index 1 and for USER the Index 2 but why it don't work ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **ImageIndex** property instead of **SelectedImageIndex**.

The first one is the index from **ImageList** for node in unselected state and the second one is applied when you select node using mouse, keyboard or through code.

Comment: if (e.Name == "FEATURE")
   node.ImageIndex = 1; 
else if (e.Name == "USER")
   node.ImageIndex = 0;